# Can not connect MemoryStore from the VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-memorystore

I have created a VM instance and MemoryStore instance in the same project but can not connect from the VM.

```
# telnet 192.168.1.4 6379
Trying 192.168.1.4...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.1.4: Connection timed out
```

The VPC to which the VM belongs is designated as an approved network of Redis, the IP of Redis is not duplicated, and VPC peering is also automatically created.
Do I need to set up firewall rules etc in addition?

VM and Redis are in the same regioins.

```
$ gcloud compute instances list --filter=name='staging-gateway'
NAME             ZONE          MACHINE_TYPE  PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP    STATUS
staging-gateway  asia-east1-a  f1-micro                   172.17.0.7   *.*.*.*  RUNNING

$ gcloud redis instances list --region asia-east1
INSTANCE_NAME             REGION      TIER         SIZE_GB  HOST         PORT  NETWORK             RESERVED_IP     STATUS  CREATE_TIME
staging-whiteboard-redis  asia-east1  STANDARD_HA  1        192.168.1.4  6379  staging-*-vpc  192.168.1.0/29  READY   2019-02-05T03:03:08
```

Comment: There is no need for firewall rules. Another restriction is that your VM has to be in the same region as your Redis instance. Could you check that?

Comment: Yes, VM and Redis are in the same asia-east1 region.

Comment: I added detailed information on VM and Redis.

Comment: When you created the VPC network, did you choose automatic subnet creation? I tried creating a custom subnet only for asia-east1 and I couldn't connect while I was able to connect when I selected automatic subnet creation.

Comment: No, I don't enable automatic subnet creation when created the VPC network.

Comment: Does it mean that I can not connect to MemoryStore unless auto subnet creation is enabled?

Comment: I created a VPC with automatic subnet creation enabled, and connected to MemoryStore.
Thank you!
But why is not it listed in the document? I hope this will be documented and fewer people suffer from the same thing

Comment: It also works with custom subnet but there is an issue with the “172.x.x.x” IP that you are using in your custom subnet. I’m posting a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to connect to your Memorystore instance, when you create the VPC network you need to either select **automatic subnet creation** or allocate a subset of one of the following IP ranges:

```
- 10.0.0.0/8
- 192.168.0.0/16
```

The issue is the internal IP allocated to your VM instance (172.17.0.7) which is trying to connect to the Memorystore instance. When you create the VPC, you should not allocate a subset of the IP range `172.17.0.0/16` to your custom subnet. That range is reserved for an internal component as seen in [Limited and unsupported networks for Memorystore](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/networking#limited_and_unsupported_networks):

> Compute Engine VM instances that have an internal IP address within
>   the range 172.17.0.0/16 cannot access Cloud Memorystore for Redis
>   instances, because that range is reserved for an internal component.

Comment: I did not know that Class B's private address had such a danger.
Certainly public and private are mixed in 172/8... Why are they not filtering at 172.16/12 ?

I recreated the VPC in class A and it was possible to connect to MemoryStore without enabling automatic subnet.
My problem was solved with this.
I'm really thankful to you!

Comment: @dkuji I edited my answer, it's actually documented that that IP range is reserved for an internal component of Memorystore.

Comment: I confirmed that it is described in the document.
I was relieved.